# FBDialogs on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-ios-sdk, fbdialogs

**What I'd like to do**

Post text to a friend's feed from my app.

or

Post text to my own feed with a tagged friend.

**What I've tried**

```
[FBDialogs presentOSIntegratedShareDialogModallyFrom:self
                                         initialText:@"Some text!"
                                              images:nil
                                                urls:nil
                                             handler:nil];
```

This doesn't work as you can't tag any friends in it neither in the text nor as a "with" tag.

```
FBShareDialogParams *params = [[FBShareDialogParams alloc] init];
params.caption = @"Some text";
params.friends = selectedFriends;
params.description = @"Some text";
params.name = @"Some text";

[FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithParams:params
                            clientState:nil
                                handler:nil];
```

This doesn't work as the fields `caption`, `description` and `name` are only used if a `link` is specified. But I don't want to specify a link.

Is there any way to ideally post to a friend's "wall"/feed. Or to at least post some text with a tagged friend?

**EDIT**

OK, by using the second method I can at least tag friends. Is there any way to set the initial text on the second method?

Answer (score 2):

There is some useful information here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/publish-open-graph-story/

You should look into using `[FBRequestConnection startForPostWithGraphPath:`